# How to dynamically convert a type to a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have some string which I want to convert to different types- usually enums.
the class holding this is a generic type so even if I have the type save I couldn't find a way of how to convert dynamically

```
                if(type.IsEnum)
                     typedValue = Enum.Parse(type, value , true);
                }
                else
                {
                    typedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value,type);
                }

                foreach (Delegate method in pair.Value)
                {

                    method.DynamicInvoke(new[] { value, typedValue, time });
                }'
```

I need to change the typed value to be not of the type save but as a generic type according to the type

Comment: CAn you give an example? because as the question stands it's very difficult to figure out exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because generics are used when you know the type only at compile-time. In your example the `type` variable represents a runtime Type.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Type` of generic arguments with `typeof`.

```
public T Convert<T>(T value)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if(type.IsEnum)
        return (T)Enum.Parse(type, value , true);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also do this with the generic argument of the class of course. But in any case, you need to know the type at compile time. Type safety is based on compiler checks. If you don't know the type at compile time, you will need to either return an `object` or a `dynamic`, unless you have a more specific type that all the involved types have in common.

---

Let's assume that you were able to create a method that returns the correct type fully dynamically.

```
var converted = Convert(type, value);

// Are you allowed to do this?
converted = 2 * converted;

// or this?
converted = converted + " hello";

// or even this?
converted.SaveAs("C:\Data\Converted.txt");
```

Since the caller does not know the type at compile-time (or even design-time), he is not able to use this type the appropriate way. This is a logical limitation, not a limitation of the language. Even with dynamic languages or with C-Sharp's `dynamic` type you need to know something about the type you are using at design-time.